alignment for ckeditor not working in next js
`
if i add alignments fucntionality from @ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment then it's show error in next js
./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/theme/placeholder.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from within node_modules.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-npm
Location: node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment/node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/placeholder.js
here is my editor code
`'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-build-classic-mathtype';
// import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';
// import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
import Alignment from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment';

export default function CkEditorMathType({
  editorLoaded,
  name,
  onChange,
  value,
}) {
  const [ckData, setCkData] = useState('');

  return (
    <>
      {editorLoaded == true && (
        <>
          <CKEditor
            editor={ClassicEditor}
            name={name}
            config={{
              plugins:[Alignment],
              toolbar: {
                // shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true,
                items: [
                  // 'heading', '|',
                  // 'fontfamily', 'fontsize', '|',
                  'Alignment', '|',
                  // 'fontColor', 'fontBackgroundColor', '|',
                  // 'bold', 'italic', 'strikethrough', 'underline', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|',
                  // 'link', '|',
                  // 'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                  // 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'todoList', '|',
                  // 'code', 'codeBlock', '|',
                  // 'insertTable', '|',
                  // 'uploadImage', 'blockQuote', '|',
                  'heading',
                  // 'fontsize',
                  // 'align',
                  // 'fontColor',
                  // 'fontBackgroundColor',
                  // 'outdent',
                  // 'indent',
                  '|',
                  'bold',
                  'italic',
                  'link',
                  'bulletedList',
                  'numberedList',
                  // 'imageUpload',
                  // 'mediaEmbed',
                  'insertTable',
                  'blockQuote',
                  // 'undo',
                  // 'redo',
                  '|',
                  'MathType',
                  'ChemType',
                ],
              },
              alignment: {
                options: ['left', 'right', 'center', 'justify'],
              },
            }}
            data={value}
            onReady={(editor) => {
              // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
              // console.log( 'Editor is ready to use!', editor );
            }}
            onChange={(event, editor) => {
              const data = editor.getData();
              onChange(data);
              // editor.setData(data)
              // console.log({ event, editor, data });
            }}
          />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}

i will also try @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic package for the edito`r

